# PrimeNG schedule fullcalendar error

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am using PrimeNG schedule in one of my project. After installing PrimeNG, I was getting error for JQuery, but after installing it the error went away. Currently i am getting this error

```
this.schedule.fullCalendar is not a function
```

Another thing I noted is that If I try to install FullCalendar, I get this message

```
calender-view@0.0.0 C:\Users\x\Desktop\Projects\calenderView
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.2.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.0
-- fullcalendar@3.8.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.13 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.46 but none was installed.
npm WARN @schematics/schematics@0.0.13 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.46 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
```

After this it is not included in package.json -> dependencies. Till now, I have install PrimeNG, moment and JQuery. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know this platform specifically (I just know about fullcalendar itself) but from the output saying "unmet depdendency" it seems like a fair guess that you probably need to install the mentioned dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution at last. (Got this answer from @Tarek-Adra's comment from this issue - https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/255)

So, I Install fullcalendar first,

```
npm install fullcalendar --save
```

And in .angular-cli.json, I made this changes,

```
"styles": [
         ...
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        ...
        "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"
      ],
...
```